# Guardar Varios Registros en una tabla sqlit3 con tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

mi consulta es la siguiente:
tengo una tabla detalleventastemporal donde guardo registros los cuales los muestro
en un treeview

Codigo Descripcion Cantidad Precio Subtotal

1       Balon        2       20      40

2       Azucar       3        5      15

3       Gaseosa      2        6      12

Ahora lo que necesito hacer es guardar todas las filas en otra Tabla
logro solo guardar el primer registro con un ciclo for pero no guarda los demas registros
con este codigo....

```
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect('Sistema')
    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DetalleFactura")
    Registros=miCursor.fetchall()
    for elementos in Registros:
        Datos=(elementos[0],elementos[1],elementos[2],elementos[3],elementos[4])
        
        miCursor.executemany("INSERT INTO DetalleVenta VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",(Datos))
        messagebox.showinfo("Guardando","Guardado correctamente")                            
    miConexion.commit() 
    miConexion.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre solucionarlo por si les sirve les dejo el codigo gracias

def GuardarFacturaDetalle(self):

```
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect('Sistema')
    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DetalleFactura")
    Registros=miCursor.fetchall()
    for elementos in Registros:
        miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO DetalleVenta VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(elementos))
                                   
    miConexion.commit() 
    self.GuardarFactura()
    miConexion.close()
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Podrías explicar de qué manera ese código soluciona el problema? Así la respuesta le ayuda a otras personas con la misma pregunta.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a tu pregunta. Luego, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).